# How do I put in more conditions in while loop?

Tags: python

I have a variable `player_answer`, I want to break the while loop when `player_answer` is equal to "yes" or "yea".

Code:

```
while player_answer != "yes" ((OR)) "yea":

            *CODE BLOCK*
```

Comment: `while player_answer not in ["yes", "yeah"]:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [complex if statement in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493404/complex-if-statement-in-python)

Comment: @prune should be fine as this combines different answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use two clauses you can use `and` /`or` for python compound logicals.

```
while not (player_answer == "yes" or player_answer == "yea"): 
   <INSERT CODE>
```

However, be careful as it's easy to get confused that way as negations with compound clauses aren't as simple as you describe above.  Specifically, the compound I wrote is **NOT** equivalent to

```
# DON'T DO THIS; THIS ILLUSTRATES A COMMON LOGICAL MISTAKE
while player_answer != "yes" or player_answer != "yea":
   <INSERT CODE>
```

For more information check out [DeMorgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

A better solution is the one from [@DeveloperXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4150352/developerxy) in the comments:

```
while player_answer not in ["yes", "yeah"]:
   <INSERT CODE>
```

Comment: the second code example didnt work for me, i tried to use it before asking, i tried to use simple logic. But the 1st and the 3rd examples worked flawlessly. thank you

Comment: the second example was intended to highlight the WRONG way to do it.  I'll make that more clear.